# parsing out in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, perl

my file looks like this

```
//
[297]((((21:0.125204,20:0.125204):0.00994299,(28:0.0790047,(7:0.0146105,5:0.0146105):0.0643943):0.0561423):0
segsites:
positions: 1 2 4 6 9 10 45 67 78 89 
01010101010101010101010101011111010101
```

I would need to parse it into three different files

```
//
[297]((((21:0.125204,20:0.125204):0.00994299,(28:0.0790047,(7:0.0146105,5:0.0146105):0.0643943):0.0561423):0
```

then

```
 segsites:
    positions: 1 2 4 6 9 10 45 67 78 89
```

an

```
 01010101010101010101010101011111010101
```

the problem is that there are not a fixed number of lines starting with the brackets and so on. the final line could start with either a 0 or an 1 and that is a problem as I dont know how to tell grep to search for either 0 or 1. I would need to grep for the []. then the segsites and the line below which includes the pos and then the numeric line with 01

Comment: 1. Is the line with brackets always followed by a `segsites` line? 2. Is `segsites` always followed by a single `positions` line? And is `positions` always followed by a single line of zeroes and ones? To grep for zeros or ones: `grep '^[01]*$'`.

Comment: for 1-2 yes...but it could be n lines all starting with [] and. Positions is followed by an hunknown number of 0 and 1 which can all start either with 0 or with 1

Comment: But any lines containing only 0s and 1s will be going to the third file? And any lines which contain `segsites` or `positions` go to the second file? And all other lines go to the first line?

Comment: yes that is the way it shoudl be

Comment: Please stop vandalising. There is nothing wrong with your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in `awk`:

```
awk '/^[01]+$/ {print > "third-file"; next} 
 /(segsites|positions)/ {print > "second-file"; next} 
 {print > "first-file"}' input-file
```

Considering three cases:

- A line containing only 0s and 1s (`/^[01]+$/`)
- A line containing either `segsites` or `positions`: `/(segsites|positions)/`
- All other lines

In each case, we print to different file and proceed to the next line.
Change `"third-file"`, `"second-file"`, `"first-file"` to appropriate names (keep the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with PCRE [`-P`] and Dotall modifier [`(?s)`]:

1st portion:

```
$ grep -Poz "(?s)^.*?(?=\nsegsites:)" file.txt 
//
[297]((((21:0.125204,20:0.125204):0.00994299,(28:0.0790047,(7:0.0146105,5:0.0146105):0.0643943):0.0561423):0
```

2nd portion:

```
$ grep -Poz "(?s)segsites.*?(?=\n[10]+$)" file.txt 
segsites:
positions: 1 2 4 6 9 10 45 67 78 89
```

In case of third portion only `grep` will do (if you have just one line):

```
$ grep -E "^[01]+$" file.txt
01010101010101010101010101011111010101
```

If you are not sure (single/multiple lines):

```
$ grep -Poz "(?<=\n)(?:[10]|\n)*(?=\n$)" file.txt 
010101010101010101010101010111110101011
01010101010101010101010101011111010101010

$ grep -Poz "(?<=\n)(?:[10]|\n)*(?=\n$)" file.txt 
010101010101010101010101010111110101011
```

Explanations:

- `grep -P` represents PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)
- `grep -o` will select only the matched portion
- `grep -z` will cause lines to be separated by ASCII NUL instead of new lines
- `(?s)` is called Dotall modifier, using this any character (including line breaks) can be matched by `.`
- `(?=)` is Positive lookahead, represents what follows our match
- `(?<)` is Positive lookbehind, represents what precedes our match