# Concatenate two files and separate them with a newline

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two files:

k.txt:

```
3 5 7 9 19 20
```

h.txt:

```
000010
100001
111001
```

if I just use cat, there is no newline. I need a command which would provide a file which looks like this:

```
3 5 7 9 19 20 
000010
100001
111001
```

Comment: What newline? How do you use `cat`? `cat k.txt h.txt > newfile` will create exactly the output you show.

Comment: @terdon unless the file itself is does not have its terminating newline... ?

Comment: My amazing psychic powers tell me that the file contents as given in the question are not the actual file contents.

Comment: Given http://askubuntu.com/questions/614271/ it becomes clear that the real files concerned are actually the (post-processed) output of a evolutionary biology simulation program named [`ms`](http://home.uchicago.edu/rhudson1/source/mksamples.html) ([doco](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-877j-computational-evolutionary-biology-fall-2005/labs/msdoc.pdf)).

Answer (score 22):

If, as steeldriver suggests, your files don't end with a newline, you could try:

```
awk '{print}' k.txt h.txt > newfile
```

or, if you like golfing

```
awk 1 k.txt h.txt > newfile
```

or

```
perl -lne 'print' k.txt h.txt
```

or

```
( cat k.txt ; echo ""; cat h.txt; echo ) > newfile
```

or

```
echo "$(cat k.txt)"; echo "$(cat h.txt)"
```

Comment: I want to edit that to `awk 1` just for how it will look. :D

Comment: @muru heh, done :)

Comment: The file has 127 MB ;)

Comment: Common, awk, perl, cat. And me?

Comment: +1. IMO the last answer is the best: the command substitution `$(cat file)` will strip any trailing newlines, and `echo` will explicitly add one. FYI, bash has a builtin for `$(cat file)` ==> `$(<file)` -- save a few microseconds. And with one command: `printf "%s\n" "$(<k.txt)" "$(<h.txt)"`

Comment: On the last two commands, could you not skip the second echo? You really only need one newline between the files, not one at the end as well.

Comment: @Oli I added it on the assumption that both files lack a final newline and that the OP would like one. I may well be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Try this with bash:

```
cat k.txt <(echo) h.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: Did you read what the questioner said about `cat` in the question?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yup, that will work. Unless neither file ends with a newline. You might want to add another `echo` to fix that.

Comment: Yes, if there is no newline in second file then a second `<(echo)` could be useful after h.txt.

Answer (score 5):

**Using `sed`:**

```
sed '/^/ r h.txt' k.txt
```

or better (thx [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver))

```
sed '$a\' k.txt h.txt
```

---

**Using `ed`:**

```
(echo "0a"; cat k.txt; echo "."; echo "wq") | ed -s h.txt
```

and for the missing newline in `k.txt`:

```
(echo "0a"; cat k.txt; echo ""; echo "."; echo "wq") | ed -s h.txt
```

or if you need a separate output file:

```
(echo "0a"; cat k.txt; echo ""; echo "."; echo "w out.txt"; echo "q") | ed -s h.txt
```

Comment: Nice! How would you do it if neither file has a newline?

Comment: The sed version will only work if k.txt has exactly one (non-terminated) line, I think? A better sed option from [How to add a newline to the end of a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955/65304) might be `sed '$a\' k.txt h.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver thx and updated =)

Answer (score 5):

That's the job for [paste](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
paste -sd'\n' file1 file2
```

- `-s` make `paste` concatenate all of the lines of each file in command line order.
- `-d'\n'` make `paste` used newline as delimiter.

Comment: Though why they didn't add one more parameter to 'cat' for this purpose (inject newlines !) I do not know ...

Comment: Much nicer and works with any number of files.

Answer (score 3):

Realizing that  the file1 might not contain the newline, why not simply add the newline by yourself ? `(cat file1.txt; printf "\n"; cat file2.txt ) > out.txt`. Alternative way to do this, would be `printf "\n" | cat file1.txt - file2.txt`

Comment: IMHO `printf "\n" | cat file1.txt - file2.txt` would be more idiomatic (and spares the life of one poor cat)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has mentioned `python` yet. Here it is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('k.txt') as fk, open('h.txt') as fh, open('out.txt', 'a') as fo:
    for line in fk:
        fo.write(line)
    fo.write('\n')
    for line in fh:
        fo.write(line)
```

Here after reading the `f.txt` file we have inserted a newline manually in the `out.txt` file (`fo.write('\n')`) and then again append the content the `k.txt` file to the `out.txt` file. Finally `out.txt` will contain the desired output.

Comment: He `python` =) +1

Comment: @A.B. Should i call you ABed or ABerl may be ;)

Answer (score 0):

`sed '' h.txt k.txt > newFile`