# get two files together

Tags: bash, regex, cat

how could I get two files together like this

`file1.txt`:

```
ROW 1 3  5 654 56 5 56 65 6 54 4 3345 35 53 3 32 2 1
ROW2  6 65 456 67 687 78 89 657  435 34 534 5 435 5 2
```

`file4.txt`:

```
01010100000000000000000000000000000101010001010
1111111111111111111100100101000101001000000000
01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

to:

```
ROW 1 3  5 654 56 5 56 65 6 54 4 3345 35 53 3 32 2 1
ROW2  6 65 456 67 687 78 89 657  435 34 534 5 435 5 2
01010100000000000000000000000000000101010001010
1111111111111111111100100101000101001000000000
01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Use `cat`:

```
cat file1.txt file4.txt
```

Comment: will there be a newline?

Comment: @user3069326  is it [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/640055/concatenate-two-files-and-separate-them-with-a-newline) again?

Comment: @user3069326 Don't you have newlines at the end of files?

Comment: @muru Seems so....

Answer (score 0):

using [cat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/catman.8.html):

```
cat file1.txt file4.txt > output.txt
```

Output:

```
$ cat output.txt

ROW 1 3  5 654 56 5 56 65 6 54 4 3345 35 53 3 32 2 1
ROW2  6 65 456 67 687 78 89 657  435 34 534 5 435 5 2
01010100000000000000000000000000000101010001010
1111111111111111111100100101000101001000000000
01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you don't want to create a new file easily:

```
cat file1.txt >> file4.txt
```

Output:

```
$ cat file4.txt

ROW 1 3  5 654 56 5 56 65 6 54 4 3345 35 53 3 32 2 1
ROW2  6 65 456 67 687 78 89 657  435 34 534 5 435 5 2
01010100000000000000000000000000000101010001010
1111111111111111111100100101000101001000000000
01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```